# Databricks: Download a dbfs:/FileStore File to my Local Machine?

Tags: curl, filesystems, databricks

I am using saveAsTextFile() to store the results of a Spark job in the folder dbfs:/FileStore/my_result.

I can access to the different "part-xxxxx" files using the web browser, but I would like to automate the process of downloading all files to my local machine.

I have tried to use cURL, but I can't find the RestAPI command to download a dbfs:/FileStore file.

**Question: How can I download a dbfs:/FileStore file to my Local Machine?**

I am using Databricks Community Edition to teach an undergraduate module in Big Data Analytics in college. I have Windows 7 installed in my local machine. I have checked that cURL and the _netrc files are properly installed and configured as I manage to successfully run some of the commands provided by the RestAPI.

Thank you very much in advance for your help! 
Best regards,
Nacho

Answer (score 35):

There are a few options for downloading FileStore files to your local machine.

**Easier options:**

- Install the [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html), configure it with your Databricks credentials, and use the CLI's `dbfs cp` command. For example: `dbfs cp dbfs:/FileStore/test.txt ./test.txt`. If you want to download an entire folder of files, you can use `dbfs cp -r`.
- From a browser signed into Databricks, navigate to `https://<YOUR_DATABRICKS_INSTANCE_NAME>.cloud.databricks.com/files/`. If you are using Databricks Community Edition then you may need to use a slightly different path. This download method described in more detail in the [FileStore docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/filestore.html).

**Advanced options:**

- Use the [DBFS REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/dbfs.html). You can access file contents using the [`read`](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/dbfs.html#read) API call. To download a large file, you may need to issue multiple `read` calls to access chunks of the full file.

Comment: Hi Josh, Thank you so much, your answer fixed the issue. I can access now to the files using the CLI. Thank you so much again! Nacho

Comment: Hi @Nacho Castiñeiras Can you please share the steps? I logged in but do not see "Access Token" tab in "User Settings", I am using Community Databricks". Thanks

Comment: Hi @NachoCastiñeiras, I too would be interested to know, how exactly you got the CLI working with the Databricks Community Edition. I am using it for my Big Data Analytics seminar too ;-)

Comment: Meanwhile the databricks CLI command would look like: 
`databricks fs cp dbfs:/FileStore/test.txt ./test.txt`

Answer (score 8):

**Quickest way to download a small file from Databricks DBFS community edition:**

When you visit Databricks community edition, the link looks like : `https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=<unique ID>`

Upload your file to folder `FileStore > tables`. Then the download link will look like:
`https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/tables/sample_file.csv?o=<your unique ID>`

*Last tested on 17-AUG-2021*

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way for me was to use display method.
[image]

Ref: https://www.learntospark.com/2021/04/download-data-from-dbfs-to-local.html

Answer (score 3):

Using browser, you can access to individual file in File Store. 
 You cannot access or even list directories. So you first have to put some file into the file store. If you've got a file "example.txt" at "/FileStore/example_directory/", you can download it via the following URL:

https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/example_directory/example.txt?o=###

In that URL, "###" has to be replaced by the long number you find at the end of your community edition URL (after you logged into your community edition account).

Add comment · Share

Comment: This is not helpful. I am able to see the file in the Filestore but not able to download locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the link like below and it worked fine for me. Even we download big files too.
You can use the link like this example below:

https://northeurope.azuredatabricks.net/files/<exact_file_path_with_folder(if_any)>?o=<your_unique_id>

e.g.
[https://northeurope.azuredatabricks.net/files/shared_uploads/mydocuments/data.json>?o=89898989899](https://northeurope.azuredatabricks.net/files/shared_uploads/mydocuments/data.json%3E?o=89898989899)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already configured Databricks CLI and its running.

Note : - We can either use 'databricks fs' or 'dbfs' interchangeably.

**Working with databricks file**

1. Copy file from databricks to your local machine

   dbfs cp < databricks path > < local repository path >

   Example :- `dbfs cp dbfs:/FileStore/PricingData/Output.csv  C:\Users\Waqar\Desktop\Output`
2. Copy file from local machine to databricks

   dbfs cp < local machine file path with file name > < databricks folder path >

   Example :- `dbfs cp C:\Users\Waqar\Desktop\Output\data.csv dbfs:/FileStore/PricingData`

**Working with databricks directory**

1. Copy directory from databricks to your local machine

   dbfs cp -r < databricks directory path > < local directory path >

   Example :- `dbfs cp -r dbfs:/FileStore/PricingData C:\Users\Waqar\Desktop\Output`
2. Copy directory from local machine to databricks

   dbfs cp -r < local machine directory path > < databricks directory path >

   Example :- `dbfs cp -r C:\Users\Waqar\Desktop\Output dbfs:/FileStore/PricingData`

Note You will have to modify your databricks path in every case. you might have to change

/dfbs/FileStore/PricingData to dbfs:/FileStore/PricingData and so on....