# How to download via URL from DBFS in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

Documented [here](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/advanced/filestore.html#id1) its mentioned that I am supposed to download a file from Data Bricks File System from a URL like:

```
https://<your-region>.azuredatabricks.net?o=######/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt
```

But when I try to download it from the URL with my own "o=" parameter similar to this:

https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/?o=1234567890123456/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt

it only gives the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /. Reason:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
"1234567890123456/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt"
```

Am I using the wrong URL or is the documentation wrong?
I already found a similar question that was answered, but that one does not seem to fit to the Azure Databricks documentation and might for AWS Databricks:

[Databricks: Download a dbfs:/FileStore File to my Local Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019706/databricks-download-a-dbfs-filestore-file-to-my-local-machine)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL should be:

https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt?o=1234567890123456

Note that the file must be in the filestore folder.

As a side note I've been working on something called DBFS explorer to help with things like this if you would like to give it a try?
https://datathirst.net/projects/dbfs-explorer/