# How can I save a spark DF as a CSV file?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have some Python code that loops through files and cretes a dataframe (DF).  Also, I am converting the Python DF to a Spark DF.  This works fine.

```
# convert python df to spark df and export the spark df
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(DF)
```

Now, I am trying to save the Spark DF as a CSV file.

```
## Write Frame out as Table
spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").save("dbfs:/rawdata/AAA.csv")
```

The code directly above runs, but it doesn't create the CSV, or at least I can't find it where I would expect it to be. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ok, this is weird.  When I run this: spark_df.write.csv(dbfs:/rawdata/AAA.csv"), it says the file already exists, but I literally can't see it anywhere!

Comment: `dbfs ls -r  /rawdata` print the output here otherwise we cant actually judge what is happening.

Comment: @asher Using databricks  notebook ? to look files , click "Data" icon on left panel of notebook, after that click "Add data" on top of that panel, then "DBFS" , see file you wrote out there.. the writes looks promising with the code you ran.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a new trick for me.  I haven't seen/tried that before.  I did what you suggested, but I don't think that helps me get my data.  I see 'AAA.csv', which is literally the name of my file, but I still don't see how I can download the results to my desktop.  I know the cloud doesn't recognize my desktop, 'per se', but there must be a way to extract items from the lake.  It shouldn't be this hard.  Ugh.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @asher if you are able to see the file in `dbfs` you're question is how to download file from `dbfs` to `local machine`. please close this question and open up the new one.

Comment: @asher, see this post helps to download your file.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019706/databricks-download-a-dbfs-filestore-file-to-my-local-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark takes path of output directory instead of output file while writing dataframe so the path that you have provided "**`dbfs:/rawdata/AAA.csv`**" will create directory **`AAA.csv`** not a file. You need to check for directory instead of file. 
In directory you will get multiple csv file based on your number of executors.

Comment: "In directory you will get multiple csv file based on your number of executors." This is incorrect.