# Databricks Cluster Get Executor Logs After Completion

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, databricks

I am running jobs on databricks clusters. When the cluster is running I am able to find the executor logs by going to Spark Cluster UI Master dropdown, selecting a worker and going through the stderr logs. However, once the job is finished and cluster terminates, I am unable to see those logs. I get below screen

[image: databricks cluster after completion]

I am unable to access the spark UI (last tab). Is there any way I can get the executor logs after cluster is terminated just like we can download the driver logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your cluster's [log delivery location](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#cluster-log-delivery).

After that, find executor logs by path `{log_delivery_location}/{cluster_id}/executor/`.

Find cluster_id in the URL of the `sparkui`. To read log files you can download them by coping into `dbfs:/FileStore/` and using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019706/databricks-download-a-dbfs-filestore-file-to-my-local-machine#:%7E:text=From%20a%20browser%20signed%20into,detail%20in%20the%20FileStore%20docs.&text=Use%20the%20DBFS%20REST%20API.).

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you --- More details [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/19342/executor-log-files-using-job-clusters.html)

> 1. Click on Jobs
> 2. Click the job you want to see logs for
> 3. Click "Logs". This will show you driver logs.
>
> For executor logs, the process is a bit more involved:
>
> 1. Click on Clusters
> 2. Choose the cluster in the list corresponding to the job
> 3. Click Spark UI
> 4. Now you have to choose the worker for which you want to see logs. Click the nodes list (it's on the far right, next to "Apps") and then
>    you can click stdout or stderr to see the logs

Comment: I saw that link.. this works while the job is running. Also it shows snapshot of logs. I want to download entire executor logs after the job is finished. just like driver logs are available.

Comment: @Tusharjain93 did you ever manage to do that? Maybe even programmatically? I am struggling with the same problem...

Comment: No Thomas, there is no way we can extract worker nodes logs